# System argument exception mvc .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, datetime

I am passing the parameters in query string. When I hover the link in the browser it shows correctly the key-value pairs in query string. When I click the link, firstly, the breakpoint is not fired at the particular action and, secondly, I got the following exception:

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter
>   'endDate' of non-nullable type 'System.DateTime' for method
>   'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult GetAllExpenses(System.String,
>   System.String, System.DateTime, System.DateTime)' in
>   'GPI.Controllers.HomeController'. An optional parameter must be a
>   reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional
>   parameter.

I understand it is asking for `endDate` parameter to not be null, but value is being passed in variable of query string. I didn't get it. Please help me to  understand this.

Initially I tried this:-

```
/Home/GetAllExpenses?userId=@ViewBag.Id&expType=debit&startDate=@quarterThreeStartDate&endDate=@quarterThreeEndDate
```

and have the same problem

after that I tried this:-

```
/Home/GetAllExpenses?userId=@HttpUtility.UrlEncode(ViewBag.Id)&expType=debit&startDate=@HttpUtility.UrlEncode(quarterThreeStartDate)&endDate=@HttpUtility.UrlEncode(quarterThreeEndDate)
```

Again I get the same exception.

This is the image of link in browser. You can see that all values of variables are there

[image]

the link in the image corresponds to 1st box i.e quarter 1 and debits

I have these following variables in my partial view which I passed to their respective links in querystring:

```
var quarterOneStartDate = new DateTime(ViewBag.Year, 1, 1);
    var quarterTwoStartDate = new DateTime(ViewBag.Year, 4, 1);
    var quarterThreeStartDate = new DateTime(ViewBag.Year, 7, 1);
    var quarterFourStartDate = new DateTime(ViewBag.Year, 10, 1);

    var quarterOneEndDate = new DateTime(ViewBag.Year, 3, 31);
    var quarterTwoEndDate = new DateTime(ViewBag.Year, 6, 30);
    var quarterThreeEndDate = new DateTime(ViewBag.Year, 9, 30);
    var quarterFourEndDate = new DateTime(ViewBag.Year, 12, 31);
```

Comment: What I usually did when I couldn't hit my breakpoints, was to build the url myself -so not yet with dynamic parameters- and try to hit the breakpoint that way. Once I got that going it becomes a lot easier to fix your issue!

Comment: You've shown us how the link looks on the server, please show us the link rendered out on the client. Maybe `quarterThreeEndDate` is not being rendered correctly, for whatever reason.

Comment: @sander It didn't succeeded your way

Answer (score -1):

Because you can't really control the data that is being sent to your controller, You should mark those fields as null-able, using `DateTime?` and than check the mandatory values for missing values and output accordingly, whatever it's an error or an action being performed successfully.